# settings for network with dhcp server

Tags: router, dhcp, local-area-network, settings

We are trying to fix a problem in a network with this setup:

DHCP Server (and all stations) connected to a gigabit switch connected to a router.

What should the Gateway and DNS values be on each of the network's stations? (Desktops, laptops etc)? I don't want actual numbers, but a general direction like: Use router's ip here, or server's ip there etc.

Comment: Need a liitle bit more detail to get a constructive answer... what is the required setup? Is this predominately a Window environment? do you have dns/dhcp installed on the Win Server? Otherwise there can be many answers to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. The default router / gateway obviously would be the internal address of your only router.

If you have special-purpose DNS servers installed (especially when using Windows Active Directory Services), you would need to use *these* servers.  Otherwise your router likely has a DNS forwarder set up and you can use the router's internal address as the DNS server setting. If it has not, you might fall back to your ISP's DNS resolver addresses (ask your ISP for details) or to public nameservers like [Google's public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) reachable at IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4.